# VueJS updating {} with $set or Vue.set does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I have function that parses my input and returns obj[] which
works correctly, but when I try to assign that local variable to this.data, then it stops working properly

```
new Vue
({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        data: {},
        source: [],
        dataIsLoaded: false
    },
    methods:
    {
        parse: function()
        {
            if (this.dataIsLoaded)
            {
                var p = getObjArray(this.source); 
                console.log("json")
                console.log(this.data);  
                console.log("p:")
                console.log(p);  
            }
        },
        loadData: function()
        {
            (...)
            this.dataIsLoaded = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Output:

[image: Works correctly]

So, it works correctly for `p`

But when I try to assign this.data = p then both of them are "empty"

```
parse: function()
{
    if (this.dataIsLoaded)
    {
        var p = getObjArray(this.source); 
        this.data = p;
        console.log("json")
        console.log(this.data); 
        console.log("p:")
        console.log(p);  
    }
},
```

Output:

[image: not working]

[image: properties]

What I have been trying:

`this.data = Object.assign({}, this.data , p);`

&&

`this.$set(this.data, 0, p[0])`

&&

`Vue.set(this.data, 0, p[0])`

All of them result in:

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
>
> (found in )

Also changing

`data: {},`

to

`data: [],`

With no success :/

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I changed instance's properties

> data: {},

to:

> data: {items: []},

and

then in `parse` method I jus tused

> this.json.data = p;